# Is hover possible in PDF?

Tags: c#, javascript, pdf, hover, tooltip

I have requirement in which we need to convert html to pdf .
Html has track change detail like underline for insertion and strike for deletion. After pdf conversion when the user hover over any of the track changed text he should be able to view the username who has done the change.We are using Aspose dll for html to pdf conversion.

Am inputs would be a great help.

Comment: I do know that you can hover over items on a PDF with alt-text. However, I do not know how to do that through code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this possible in PDF? Yes, it is.

Some examples:

- [http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter07/movie_posters_2.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20140309010301/http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter07/movie_posters_2.pdf)
- [http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter07/calculator.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20141127010800/http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter07/calculator.pdf)
- [http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter07/timetable_help.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20130302035051/http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter07/timetable_help.pdf)
- browse the examples of chapter 7 of my book for more...

Is this possible with Aspose? I have no idea; I'm mr. iText, not mr. Aspose ;-)

**Edit:** [Link rot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262038/how-to-flag-dead-links) is a thing and posting answers that only containing external sources is always a bad idea. It would be a good idea to include an example of how to do it.

Comment: Yes, the fact that the annotation corresponds with an image is a coincidence; all you need it a Rectangle to position the annotation.

Comment: Could you please share your books or any other link where we can learn ?